# How use different Android XML for production and testing without using multiple files?

Tags: java, android, xml

The testing build of my application has a couple different features from the production build. I use a static constant in the main activity to differentiate them:

```
static final boolean TestingBuild = true;
// ...
if ( TestingBuild ) {
    initNewFeature();
}
```

But the two builds also need differences in the XML layout files. For instance, the testing build needs a button that activates the new feature. How can I solve this?

My current solution is to load different XML files depending on `TestingBuild`, but that leads to a lot of duplicate XML code. Further, I need to edit two XML files instead of one when I need to make a change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way then having multiple XML layouts for your situation. But you can get rid of duplicate code by using the [include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) and [merge](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge) tags.

Define one releaseable layout and include your testing layout, with some views just for testing.

Something like this:

The testing_layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height=".."
    android:layout_width=".."
    ...
/>
```

The testing layout is a simple example. You can use a surrounding ViewGroup, if you like.

The release_layout:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <TextView.../>
      <Button.../>
      <include layout="@layout/testing"
          <!-- here you can redefine android:layout_ tags of the included layout -->
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

With this you can add portions of the UI without having duplicate code, which is better to use and to maintain. But you still need two layouts one for the release without include and one for testing with the include. Decide yourself which is saving you more code to include the testing in the release layout or the other way around.